# Find the constants to make it continuous.

Tags: calculus, continuity, constants

I am having trouble starting this question. 
Find the constants (a, b or c) to make the function continuous.

f(x)= {

```
       x^-1  if x<-1
       ax+b  if -1 ≤ x ≤ 1/2
       x^-1  if x > 1/2
```

}
I know that if you had only two function, you would set them equal to each other, plug in and solve for the variable, but here I don't know how I could do that.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

You need to have continuity at the points where the function's definition is changing. So you need
\begin{align*}
f(-1) & = \lim_{x \to -1}f(x)\\
f(1/2) & = \lim_{x \to 1/2}f(x).
\end{align*}
Now solve for $a,b$.